# Using Node.js I get readFileSync is not a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript

I am developing a web app with Angular 2, typescript, nodejs and Visual Studio. I want to read a file located in my wwwroot folder. so far I have created the following class:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/ts/typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
export class LoadConfigurationService {
    fs: any;
    constructor() {
        this.fs = require('fs');
        let data = this.fs.readFileSync('input.txt');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I always get the error `"readFileSync is not a function"`. I have tried to install the node file system module by adding the following line

```
"file-system": "^2.2.1"
```

to my package.json dependencies. I've also added

```
"node.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped": "2.8.8"
```

to my project.json dependencies. But it keeps giving me the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you would try requiring fs outside of your constructor?
as in: ```var fs = require('fs'); 
 constructor()...```

Comment: it still does not work

Comment: what do you get if you do `console.log(this.fs)` ? or `console.log(Object.keys(this.fs))` ?

Comment: what is the generated code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, such as it is. What error are you getting? Here's the (slightly amended) ts:

```
declare var require: any;

export class LoadConfigurationService {
  fs: any;
  public data: string;
  constructor() {
    this.fs = require('fs');
    this.data = this.fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString();
  }
}

const obj = new LoadConfigurationService();
console.log(obj.data);
```

Run this through `tsc` v1.8.7 produces:

```
"use strict";
var LoadConfigurationService = (function () {
    function LoadConfigurationService() {
        this.fs = require('fs');
        this.data = this.fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString();
    }
    return LoadConfigurationService;
}());
exports.LoadConfigurationService = LoadConfigurationService;
var obj = new LoadConfigurationService();
console.log(obj.data);
```

Run this with a suitable `input.txt` (consisting of "File Contents", for me) in the local directory and get:

```
$ node temp.js
File Contents
```

### Possible problems

There are a couple issues I can see that might get in your way.

#### The code depends on the native node `fs`, not `"file-system": "^2.2.1"`

The worth of the [referenced npmjs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system) aside, you are invoking the native `fs` library.

#### Don't require a dependency inside a constructor.

Dependencies for objects is a problem and worth reading about, but this is not a good way to handle it. `fs` should be immutable, so there's no advantage to requiring it each time the object is constructed. Just one line at the top of the file will do:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

#### `fs` inside Angular?

I'm not sure what the snippet has to do with Angular, but if this code is getting webpacked or browserified things will become difficult. `fs` is for file system access and bundling that into the browser will not end well.